# Excel formula with conditional formatting returning incorrect value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my table

[image]

How to achieve this using conditional formatting?
values can be negative too
-1 is > -2 .

Below are formula I have tried and it didn't work

```
=$C$2<$D$2
=$C$2>$D$2
=$C$2=$D$2
```

[image]

Comment: You have to remove the $-sign before the row number --> `=$C2 < $D2`. Without that the formula is relative to its position.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rules to apply to the entire column, you need to refer to the cells in row 1, not in row 2.

And since the row number is variable, you have to remove the $ signs from before the row number:

```
=$C1<$D1

=$C1>$D1

=$C1=$D1
```